# Filter an array of objects, by keys in filter object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

i'm new here, i have problem that i can not solve.
I have 2 different arrays:

The first array - contains ratings of users with their ID name

```
[
{"handle":"frontend1", "_redis":"3", "_nodejs":"5", "_mysql":"2", "_python":"3", "_mongo":"4"},
{"handle":"frontend3", "_php":"4", "_mysql":"4", "_oracle":"4", "_ruby":"3", "_mongo":"5", "_python":"5"},
{"handle":"frontend4", "_java":"5", "_ruby":"5", "_mysql":"5", "_mongo":"5"}
]
```

The second set - contains the ratings, which I want to return to each user.
If there is a rating that is not in the second set, I will not return it

In the second set, values do not matter, only keys

```
[
      "_assembler",
      "_css",
      "_python",
      "_php"
    ]
```

I want to return to the first set, the handle, and all the rankings that exist in the second set.

```
[
{"handle":"frontend1", "_python":"3" },
{"handle":"frontend3", "_php":"4", "_python":"5" },
{"handle":"frontend4"}
]
```

this is what i try to do.

```js
keys = [
  "_assembler",
  "_css",
  "_python",
  "_php"
]

source = [
{"handle":"frontend1", "_redis":"3", "_nodejs":"5", "_mysql":"2", "_python":"3", "_mongo":"4"},
{"handle":"frontend3", "_php":"4", "_mysql":"4", "_oracle":"4", "_ruby":"3", "_mongo":"5", "_python":"5"},
{"handle":"frontend4", "_java":"5", "_ruby":"5", "_mysql":"5", "_mongo":"5"}
];

result = [];
tmp = {};

source.forEach((item) => {
Object.keys(item).map(({key,value}) =>
  {
  if(key == "handle")
  {
    tmp[key]=value;
  }
  if(keys.includes(key))
  {
    tmp[key]=value;
  }
  })
  result.push(...tmp);
  tmp = {};
});
```

Comment: why did `frontend` change to `backend`?

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks so much for the help, I did not notice, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `map` utilizing a couple of other array methods such as `filter`, and Object methods.

```js
const keys = [
  "_assembler",
  "_css",
  "_python",
  "_php"
]

const source = [
{"handle":"frontend1", "_redis":"3", "_nodejs":"5", "_mysql":"2", "_python":"3", "_mongo":"4"},
{"handle":"frontend3", "_php":"4", "_mysql":"4", "_oracle":"4", "_ruby":"3", "_mongo":"5", "_python":"5"},
{"handle":"frontend4", "_java":"5", "_ruby":"5", "_mysql":"5", "_mongo":"5"}
];

const result = source.map( s => ({
  handle: s.handle,
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(s).filter(x => x[0] != "handle" && keys.includes(x[0])))
}));

console.log(result);
```